# Working out number of days between 2 dates based on a specific premise

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I'm wondering if anyone can help me. I have a spreadsheet which I use to populate scheduled meetings of various venues (at the moment these dates I enter in manually from a reference sheet as I don’t know how to do it with a formula).

Each week, when staff go to the venue for their meeting I then enter in (again manually) what date they actually went to the venue for the meeting.

What I then have to do, is work out if they went to the meeting within our agreed time-frame, and if not, how many days late were they. However, this calculation part will just take days to do by hand as there are so many meetings to analyse.

To work out if someone is within time frame or is late, it works on this premise:

If your meeting was scheduled to take place in say week 40, you have until the Friday of week 41 to go. Any working day after that is a day late (so if for example you ended up going to the meeting on the Tuesday in week 42 you would be 2 days late). Weekends and holidays should not be included in the calculation as staff don't work on bank holidays.

The link shows an example of how this looks - you can pretty much ignore the first tab as that's just me working out some example dates to put into the main tab and the last tab is the bank holidays for the remainder of this year and next.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KaEAB59311W8_M1FdAL96753SirqY3dtl4eTzIruzK8/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks so much in advanced for reading this, and if anyone is able to help or has any ideas on how to even get started with this I’d really welcome your thoughts !

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this was my best attempt at this for the time I've got now - This will work if the max amount of time that a scheduled meeting can take place is up to 2 weeks beyond the original limit - anything more than that and it will be off, but you could change that `IF` formula to account for that:

`=IF(D2-(B2+13-WEEKDAY(B2))<0,0,IF(D2-(B2+13-WEEKDAY(B2))>7,D2-(B2+13-WEEKDAY(B2))-4,D2-(B2+13-WEEKDAY(B2))-2))`

[image: img1]

Screenshot from posted file:

[image: img2]

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to look at this ! I had a go at playing around with this, but I'm not sure which tab you were looking at; was it the raw data or main page tab? I tried the formula in the main page tab but changing all the cells to D3, C3 etc but it doesn't seem to work.

However with regards to your second point, annoyingly meetings could take place well after 2 weeks.

Comment: @Eve I took an exact copy of your "Raw Data" worksheet and replaced your hard coded values in column E with the formula above.

Comment: @Eve Could meeting take place a *year* after the scheduled date? What's the max amount of time?

Comment: thanks for your reply. 
There literally is no maximum amount of time, and also , if its say scheduled for end of December it could take place in the new year. 
We do try and get things booked in as soon as we can, but if for example someone is sick, it could end up being a month later than initially planned.